# Python installs packages into my current directory even though I have setup virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've installed pip and virtualenv (with sudo) and I've created my first python app using [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage). I've also run `virtualenv my_app` followed by `source ~/virt/bin/activate`.

But when I cd to my app, `cd /vagrant` and run `python setup.py test` I see the eggs and packages I need are all downloaded into my app, i.e. the current directory.

I was sort of expecting them to go into **~/virt/**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should be ./my_app/bin/activate. With the above you are looking for a virtualenv named virt in your home directory, which is likely not what you want.

Assuming that you created an application called my_app in your home directory you would need to call 
    source ~/my_app/bin/activate
in order to create it

You can find more usage information [here.](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage)